# Is there a specific time to revered with serial up/downvotes?

Tags: discussion

This might have been asked before, but just to clear I am asking because when it's too much clear that you've been downvoted as a target? Is there any rollback?

I have read threads saying just refresh and come back, but still it hurts when you know that you have been targeted by someone just because you tried to give them a better answer or correct their posts.

This three downvotes came in a second and it hurts, and all those three questions have accepted answers like one year ago!

Isn't this reversing the motivation to help someone out?

[image]

Comment: [The job runs at 03:00 UTC](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: @honk that link is helpful :) yes my question is a duplicate sorry about that couldn't find the right post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, it takes up to 24 hours until the automated systems reverse serial voting. If this doesn't happen, [contact](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) Stack Exchange and describe, what happened.